# error: (-27) NULL array pointer is passed in function cvGetMat?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am new to open cv. i am getting  the problem when trying to find the rectangle with counters.

Here is my full code. Find the Counters and try to get the points

```
 IplImage* newimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* cannyimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* greyimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* testimg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

// convert the loaded image to a canny image
cvCvtColor(img, greyimg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvCanny(greyimg, cannyimg, 50, 150, 3);

// necessary to convert loaded image to an image with channel depth of 1
cvConvertImage(cannyimg, newimg);
cvConvertImage(img, testimg);

// allocate necessary memory to store the contours
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvMemStorage* canny_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

// find the contours in both the loaded image and the canny filtered image
cvFindContours(testimg, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
               CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE);
cvFindContours(newimg, canny_storage, &canny_contours, sizeof(CvContour),
               CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE);

for( CvSeq* c=canny_contours; c!=NULL; c=c->h_next)
{
    CvRect Rects = cvBoundingRect( c );
    NSLog(@"%d",Rects.x);
    NSLog(@"%d",Rects.y);
    NSLog(@"%d",Rects.width);
    NSLog(@"%d",Rects.height);
}
```

Comment: Your code is too much abbreviated. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "I am new to opencv" - so please avoid the outdated c-api.